# Cannot use Controls.Add in WPF application

Tags: c#

When I write Controls.Add() to dynamically create a control in a window, it says that Controls is not defined or present in window class. In other words "Controls" is not being recognized as a class or command and hence the code is not working. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

I want to dynamically create a window and add a textbox to it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

 public partial class Window2 : Window
    {
        public Window2()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
        } 

private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window f1 = new Window();
            f1.Show();
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Width = 150;
            tb.Height = 60;
            tb.Name = "TextBoxID";
            tb.Text = "This is textbox first data";
            Controls.Add(f1);  


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation for the [Window Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you'll notive it has no such property. It has a `Content` property which you can set to one control. So if you want to add multiple controls you must set the window's `Content` property to a multi-item panel such as a StackPanel or Grid, and add controls to the panel.

[Panels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx#inheritanceContinued)

Comment: Can you plz provide the code.  The objective is to enter value in textbox of window1 and then clicking on a button on window1 a new window2 opens and displays the contents of the textbox1 of window1 in textbox2 of window2. Can this simple task be done without using bindings?